# What happens if the host cancels my reservation through Booking.com?

Tags: regulations, cancellations, booking.com

I booked through booking.com recently. After having the reservation I bought the plane tickets and I have everything set up for the trip.

The reservation was auto-confirmed. Meanwhile, I got a message from the host saying he couldn't host me anymore.
I can't do anything about it since I already have everything prepared. Prices are rising fast and I will not get anything at reasonable prices.

I searched and got some information saying that if the host cancels I can request an alternative to booking.com and even compensation. These are just informal forums though.
https://partner.booking.com/en-gb/community/just-joined-bookingcom/cancellation-host

I would like to find some official source where this is clearly stated. The general terms and conditions don't mention this.

**Can a host just cancel a reservation without any penalty or without giving alternatives? What happens, aren't there any service guarantees from booking.com?**

Does anyone know where to find this information or did someone have a similar experience? How did it turn out?

Comment: I'd be very surprised if you had recompense against booking.com.  I'd guarantee it's in their terms that they can't be held responsible for a bad host or a problem with the host. They'll say to vote or leave a comment or whatever for the booking.

Comment: Hi @MarkMayo , I just added the link where it mentions that the host will pay for your relocation. It makes sense that booking.com offers some sort of guarantee. These systems are based on trust.

Comment: @nsn What did the terms you agreed to state?  The cancellation terms should always be clearly noted when you agree to something.

Comment: @gerrit that's exactly what I want to find out. I have a faint idea that there is some sort of guarantee, but I don't remember all the terms exactly.

Comment: Was the reservation actually confirmed initially, or was it somehow pending confirmation?

Comment: How long ago did you make the reservation? I had one host cancel my bookings like 3-4 times until I gave up and booked another hotel, but it was for a same-night reservation.

Comment: @jcaron yes, the reservation was confirmed. They sent me an initial message apologizing saying that they forgot to block the dates and asked me to cancel. It sounds weird, it was a new property and was completely vacant when I booked, but I am not even going into that.

Comment: @nsn That sounds odd - is the accommodation advertised on other websites? Is it a hotel or a private rental (maybe even an AirBnB property)?

Comment: Possibly someone renting their own property when they are away which did not quite understand how things work. Or they put it on several sites at the same time and didn't add bookings from one to the other (but they shouldn't use automatic confirmation in that case). But that doesn't quite help you. The Booking.com conditions are extremely vague and mostly "we're only a platform, the conditions applicable are those of the supplier". You can still try to contact them, they have quite a lot of leverage over hosts.

Comment: This has happened to me in the past. Back then booking.com helped me to book a new property. The value was a bit more expensive, the place not so nice, but it was fine. I didn't even bother much.  Now it's different. I can manage for myself, but I am traveling with family. I am in charge of booking and I want them to have a positive experience. Prices are going up very fast.

Comment: @nsn Leaving aside the annoyance, why would you trust a host who has already proved themselves unreliable to find you alternative accommodation?

Comment: The answer will depend on local law. In which country is the host located?

Answer (score 3):

This isn't by far a canonical answer, but yet it can be useful to someone else.

The host informed me that he couldn't host me anymore. I was already preparing for a cancelation, yet I informed him that that wouldn't be possible and asked for viable alternatives. Against all my expectations he answered back that he would keep my reservation and he didn't cancel.

My advice, given this scenario, is: don't cancel immediately, otherwise the burden to find a new place is all on you. This can become a nightmare if it's short term to travel and everything is booked.